# Why is "unhandled promise rejection" a thing?

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, promise

I understand when the `UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning` error happens.
What I don't understand is *why* the the spec was written in such a way as to allow this behavior.

For example, the following code is bad, if `callApi()` rejects than we get the `UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning` error in Node a similar error in each browser:

```
class A {
    constructor () {
        this._stuff = Promise.reject(Error('oops'))
    }
    getStuff () {
        return this._stuff
    }
}

const a = new A()

setTimeout(() => {
    a.getStuff().catch(err => console.log('I caught it!'))
}, 100)
```

But why?! I tend to thing of promises as abstracting over *when* stuff happens.
That's exactly how the promise acts if `callApi()` is successful: the caller of `getStuff()` will get the stuff when the data is available.

But the rejection case doesn't work the same way. What I'd expect to happen (if I hadn't been burned by this before) is for the burden of handling the error to fall to the caller of `getStuff`. That's not how it works, but why?

Comment: I'm not sure I fully understand what you need. If `getStuff` is successful, the .`then` callback on `getStuff()` will fire, if it failed, the `.catch` is fired. How is the rejection case different from success case?

Comment: why the vote down?

Comment: @JohanP I'd expect the *caller* of getStuff() to receive the rejection and for there to be no unhandled promise rejection error.

Answer (score 1):

The detection of an unhandled promise rejection is imperfect in node.js.  I don't know exactly how it works internally, but if you don't have a `.catch()` in a promise chain and that promise rejects, even if you assign it to a variable and then later add a `.catch()` to it, then it will give you the "unhandled rejection warning".

In your specific case, it is probably because you got back to the event loop with a rejected promise that wasn't caught - your `.catch()` is only added later on a subsequent event.  There's no way for the node.js interpreter to know that you're going to do that.  It sees that an event finished executing and a rejected promise was not handled so it creates the warning.

To avoid the warning, you will have to code it differently.  You don't really show a real world use so we can see what you're trying to accomplish to make a specific suggestion.  As with other types of things like this, the best way to handle it varies depending upon the real world use case.

---

If you're asking why an unhandled rejection is a warning at all, then that's because it can be a serious error and if there was no warning, then it would simply fail silently and the developer would never be the wiser.  It's very much akin to an unhandled exception in synchronous code.  That's a serious error and aborts the program.  node.js has been notifying for awhile that an unhandled rejection may get the same treatment in the future.  For now, it's just a warning.

Comment: thanks for your answer, but I was asking why it works this way. I understand the error.

Comment: @MaxHeiber - Because an unhandled rejection is very much like an unhandled exception in synchronous code.  It's a serious error and should not be left to silently fail with nobody knowing it happened.

Comment: @MaxHeiber - You may want to clarify your question.  It says "But why?", but it isn't clear exactly what you're asking about there.  I thought you were asking "why did this code get an unhandled rejection when I added a `.catch()`"?  If you meant to ask something different than that, then please edit your question to clarify.

Comment: I struggled with the wording. I came up with "I understand when the UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning error happens. What I don't understand is why the the spec was written in such a way as to allow this behavior." How can I make this clearer?

Comment: @MaxHeiber - Are you just asking this: "Why did they make an unhandled promise rejection be a warning in node.js?"  Or, are you asking: "Why are you allowed to write code that doesn't have a `.catch()` handler for every promise?".

Comment: I'm asking something more specific than your first question: "What I don't understand is why the the spec was written in such a way as to allow this behavior." Where "this behavior" is that unhandled promise rejections lead to warnings. Ideally, we could just write code like in my example.

Comment: @MaxHeiber - Because it is not possible to tell that sometime in the future you are going to add a `.catch()` handler.  When your code finishes executing and returns to the event loop to wait for the next event, there is no `.catch()` handler on a promise that has rejected.  That's an unhandled rejection at that time.  There is no way for the interpreter to know that your code is going to add a `.catch()` to it sometime in the future.

Comment: @MaxHeiber - Also, I can't find a node.js specification that covers this behavior.  It's not in the ES6 specification that I can find.  In an effort to add this capability to browsers, your particular situation is discussed here: https://github.com/zloirock/core-js/issues/72

Comment: @MaxHeiber - Here's a discussion of working on the feature: https://github.com/promises-aplus/unhandled-rejections-spec/issues/1 which morphs into this: https://github.com/nodejs/node/issues/830 which describes more specifics of an implementation in https://gist.github.com/benjamingr/0237932cee84712951a2